# How to select current element to apply hover effect? not inherited

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to select exact element to apply hover effect. But not inherited.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> <-- not here
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="child"></div> <-- apply hover effect
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is it possible by only CSS ?
If it is not possible by only CSS, you can give me idea angularjs directive. 
Goal is I want to make a reuseable, scaleable angularjs directive or CSS class.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
More clear structure.

```
<div class="custom-scroller">
    <div class="custom-scrollbar"> <-- not here
        <dynamic-multi-layer-elements>
            ... <-- lots of dynamic number of elements here
            <div class="custom-scroller"> <-- it might be many times nested
                <div class="custom-scrollbar"></div> <-- apply hover effect
            </div>
            ... <-- lots of elements closed
        </dynamic-multi-layer-elements>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .custom-scroller .custom-scrollbar .custom-scroller > custom-scrollbar:hover
{
color:#000;
}

Comment: I don't know how many times it is gonna be nested. It is nested itself.

Comment: But is the custom scrollbar added dynamically as well?

Comment: yes, custom scroller is container.

Comment: How many .custom-scrollbars exist after adding dynamic content? Only two?

Comment: Many. I don't wanna show scrollbars everywhere. I just wanna show current scrollable scrollbar.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
.parent > .child > .parent > .child:hover
{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent .parent > .child:hover
{
color:green;
}
```

you can do it like that